# Latex Beamer: Error puts 3.33pt at the top of every toc frame

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

```
l.1 \beamer@endinputifotherversion
                                   {3.33pt}
? 
) (C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ts1cmss.fd)
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1{C:/User
s/krishna/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]....
(FILENAME.toc
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My guess is based solely on the command at the top of your question body.  If I'm incorrect, I agree with the first commenter that it would really help if you wrote some text explaining your problem.